# AngularJS html form binding?

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind-html

I need to use form tags in ng-bind-html? The ng-bind-html is not binding form tags(form, input). Please provide solution to bind form tags.

Comment: Please provide attempt to bind form tags.

Answer (score 1):

ng-bind-html doesn't work fine with Form elements. However you can achieve it by either creating a separate directive to compile the given HTML or by using $templateCache.

http://plnkr.co/edit/UbEUmJ?p=preview